# Отображение балуна кластеризованной метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть кластер. В нем две метки с одинаковыми координатами. При изменении масштаба карты кластер на разбивается на отдельные метки из-за близкого их расположения.

Вопрос: как открыть балун одной из этих меток?

Насколько я понял метки на карту не добавлены, поскольку находятся в кластере, соответственно открыть их балун простым `myPlacemark.balloon.open()` не получится, вылазит ошибка `getGlobalPixelCenter`.

Вроде как можно открыть `myMap.baloon.open()` но тут нельзя задать `balloonContentLayout` классом из `templateLayoutFactory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете открыть балун кластера с выбранной меткой https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_balloon_open

> Вроде как можно открыть myMap.baloon.open() но тут нельзя задать balloonContentLayout классом из templateLayoutFactory

Конечно можно. Но так как вы задаете опцию сразу балуну, то звучать она будет так:

```
contentLayout: BalloonContentLayout
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d1seomp5/

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению оба варианта в моем случае не подходят. Кластер у меня без балуна, а во втором случае не отрабатывают события balloonopen и balloonclose, кнопка "закрыть" вообще не работает ну и сам балун почему-то не позиционируется по точке, а отображается в углу карты шириной в 150px ( при этом если не задать layout то позиционируется нормально). Но все равно спасибо за совет!

Comment: balloonopen и balloonclose, я не знаю где вы слушаете эти события, но наверно если на балуне, то это должны быть события open и close. Всё должно работать) кидайте пример на jsfiddle разберемся)